# How to draw a line between two points in LibGDX, in 3D

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

I'm trying to learn the 3D side of LibGDX, and I've came to a problem. I want to draw a line from `0, 0, -5` to `0, 0, 5`. I've tried a few things to make this work.
First I looked to see if I could create a line as a `Model`. As far as I can see, I can't do this.
What I then realised is that theoretically I can draw a line using a `ShapeRenderer`. Here's my code to try to do this.

```
public class Main implements ApplicationListener {
    ...
    public ShapeRenderer srend;
    ...
    @Override
    public void create() {
        ...
        srend = new ShapeRenderer();
        srend.setColor(Color.RED);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        ...
        srend.begin(ShapeType.Line);
        srend.line(0, 0, -5, 0, 0, 5);
        srend.end();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But for some reason this doesn't appear to work. I use ShapeRenderers a lot, but it's possible that I'm making a mistake initializing or using it, I don't think that's the problem though.
I've only just started using the 3D part of LibGDX, so I assume the problem is around where I'm drawing the actual line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Model Builder works well for me.

```
ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.begin();
MeshPartBuilder builder = modelBuilder.part("line", 1, 3, new Material());
builder.setColor(Color.RED);
builder.line(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f);
lineModel = modelBuilder.end();
lineInstance = new ModelInstance(lineModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set camera matrix before rendering:

```java
@Override
    public void create() {
        ...
        srend = new ShapeRenderer();
        srend.setProjectionMatrix(new Matrix4())
        srend.setColor(Color.RED);
        ...
    }
```

I don't know why, but this helps. Matrix4() is just identity matrix. With identity camera matrix right side of the screen has coordinate 1, left -1. So if coordinates inside cube -1..1, you should see them.

In real code (for example, for drawing gizmos in 3d world) you can set matrix from PerspectiveCamera:

```java
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)
```